# How to print from Xamarin application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, printing, uwp

Is it possible to print from a xamarin application to a pos printer?

I search in xamarin docs about printing but i only found a microsoft UWP sample. Is this for xamarin development also? Probably i miss something so can anyone guide me how to print from a xamarin application silently to a ECS/POS printer?

Comment: You need to read the printer manual.  There is no general solution for this - you need to connect to the printer with bluetooth, then the specific details of printing will depend on the printer

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin supports .NET Core technology. Xamarin.Forms is the user interface technology. Printing is something that is not covered with either of those.

You can print with Xamarin.Forms as each platform (iOS, Android, UWP etc) supports printing and Xamarin supports 100% of APIs of each platform, however you need to write the code separately, for example for UWP you can use the link you found above, but it will work only on UWP.